# Upload Salesforce user profile photo via rest

Tags: rest-api, rest, user, user-profile

I am entirely new at this. I want to know if it is possible to upload the user record profile picture via rest.

I found that the photo url is exposed via the following

/services/data/v41.0/connect/user-profiles/

I would like to understand where exactly is the photo uploaded and if there is any sample code to test if I can upload the photo via rest.

Answer (score 4):

This is outlined in [Inputs and Binary File Upload Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#cc_upload_binary_files) and [Update and Crop a User Photo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_update_crop_user_photo.htm).

Basically, you can use an already-uploaded file:

```
POST /services/data/v42.0/connect/user-profiles/005-userId/photo HTTP/1.1
<<other headers>>

{   "cropSize" : "240",
    "cropX" : "20",
    "cropY" : "20",
    "fileId" : "069D00000001IOh"
}
```

Or you can upload/crop a new photo:

```
POST /services/data/v42.0/chatter/users/me/photo HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth 00DD0000000Jhd2!AQIAQC.lh4qTQcBhOPm4TZom5IaOOZLVPVK4wI_rPYJvmE8r2VW8XA.
OZ7S29JEM_7Ctq1lst2dzoV.owisJc0KacUbDxyae
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
Host: ***instance_name***
Content-Length: 543
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq
Accept: application/json

--a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{
   "cropX" : "0",
   "cropY" : "0",
   "cropSize" : "200"
}

--a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="myPhoto.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1

...contents of myPhoto.jpg...

--a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq--
```

Please read the attached documentation; this only outlines the bare minimum that you'd need to know.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I get an error saying `The requested resource does not exist` when I use API version 42.0. If I use 34.0 I don't get this message, but rather `The request API is not available to portal users. You may need to specify a community for portal user access.` Do you think the first error might be caused by the same permission error as in version 34?

Comment: @Folkert The portal user API has a different endpoint, I think.You might want to ask a new question with those details and what you've tried so far. I really only have experience with internal users, not portal users, so it's likely someone else would know more than I.